# Using copy ctor instead of move ctor when derived has destructor defined

Tags: c++, gcc

When I add a destructor to my derived class, I get compiler errors (using gcc 4.7) when it tries to use the copy ctor instead of the defined move ctor:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Base 
{
  T value;

  Base(T&& value) :
    value(value)
  {
    std::cout << "base ctor" << std::endl;
  }

  Base& operator=(const Base&) = delete;
  Base(const Base&) = delete;

  Base& operator=(Base&& rhs)
  {
    value = rhs.value;
    std::cout << "move assignment" << std::endl;
  }

  Base(Base&& other) :
    value(other.value)
  {
    std::cout << "move ctor" << std::endl;
  }

  virtual ~Base()
  {
    std::cout << "base dtor" << std::endl;
  }
};

template <typename T>
struct Derived : public Base<T>
{
  Derived(T&& value) :
    Base<T>(std::forward<T>(value))
  {
    std::cout << "derived ctor" << std::endl;
  }

  ~Derived()
  {
    std::cout << "derived dtor" << std::endl;
  }
};

template <typename T>
Derived<T> MakeDerived(T&& value)
{
  return Derived<T>(std::forward<T>(value));
}

struct Dummy {};

int main()
{
  auto test = MakeDerived(Dummy());
}
```

This code compiles fine on gcc-4.5 and gcc-4.6. The errors from gcc-4.7 are:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:61:34: error: use of deleted function ‘Derived<Dummy>::Derived(const Derived<Dummy>&)’
test.cpp:37:8: note: ‘Derived<Dummy>::Derived(const Derived<Dummy>&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
test.cpp:37:8: error: use of deleted function ‘Base<T>::Base(const Base<T>&) [with T = Dummy; Base<T> = Base<Dummy>]’
test.cpp:16:3: error: declared here
test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Derived<T> MakeDerived(T&&) [with T = Dummy]’:
test.cpp:61:34:   required from here
test.cpp:54:43: error: use of deleted function ‘Derived<Dummy>::Derived(const Derived<Dummy>&)’
```

Am I missing something here or should this also compile fine on gcc 4.7? When I comment out the destructor on the Derived class all is well.

```
gcc version 4.5.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.3-12ubuntu2) 
gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 
gcc version 4.7.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-11precise2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is correct; move constructors are only implicitly generated when the class has no user-defined destructor. If you add a destructor, then you're suppressing the default move-constructor, and the copy constructor is attempted. The generation of a default copy-constructor is suppressed when a class has a noncopyable base class, as yours is, so `Derived` is neither copyable nor movable.

The solution is simply to add a move-constructor to `Derived`.

Comment: I've not needed to declare a move constructor for a derived class with no members of it's own (besides those in the base class). 
`Derived(Derived&& other) : Base<T>(other) { }` calls the base class copy constructor, so I tried an explicit std::move instead, which works. Is that correct?

Comment: @Troy yes, that is correct, you need the `move`. The reason you haven't needed to have move-constructors up to now is because compilers are only now starting to gain stricter conformance to the standard.